# Grant IIS 7.5 Application Pool Read Permission to Certificate Private Key by Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, certificate, iis-7.5

I searched all around and could not find a lot of information, basically I have Windows 2008 R2, I created PowerShell script to load a PFX file to certificate store of Local Machine already.

Now I need to grant permission of my app pool to read the private key of the certificate by using PowerShell.

In the old way Windows 2003, I just need to get the actual file sitting in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\` folder, but it looks like Win 2008 uses a different folder.

Anybody has some solution?

-- Update my version of code --

```
function Grant-CertificatePermissions([string]$certSubject,[string]$user,[string]$permissionType,[string]$permission = $args[3])
{
    $getCert = Get-LocalMachineCertificate $certSubject
    $keypath = Get-CertificateStorePath
    $certHash = $getCert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
    $certFullPath = $keypath+$certHash
    $certAcl = Get-Acl -Path $certFullPath

    try
    {
        $accessRule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $user, $permissionType, $permission
        $certAcl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
        throw "Invalid User Id Or Permission"
    }
    Set-Acl $certFullPath $certAcl
}

function Get-LocalMachineCertificate([string]$subject, [string]$certificateStoreLocation, [string]$certificateStoreName)
{
    $getCert = Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\$certificateStoreLocation\$certificateStoreName | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq $subject}

    if(!$getCert)
    {
        throw "Certificate Not Found"
    }

    return $getCert
}

function Get-CertificateStorePath
{
    $commonCertPathStub = "\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\"
    $programData = $Env:ProgramData
    if(!$programData)
    {
        $programData = $Env:ALLUSERSPROFILE + "\Application Data"
    }

    $keypath = $programData + $commonCertPathStub

    return $keypath
}
```

In my `Get-CertificateStorePath` function I get value as `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\`, after I get certificate hash, the complete file looks like `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\d82829f7770ea5d85ef978dea67f302d_4cca7190-7e9f-46d7-b180-6656fec432e2`, when I execute `Get-Acl` line I have exception `Cannot find path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\d82829f7770ea5d85ef978dea67f302d_4cca7190-7e9f-46d7-b180-6656fec432e2' because it does not exist.`.

I browsed that folder, I indeed could not find such a file.

-- Update --

```
function Import-PfxCertificate ([String]$certPath,[String]$certificateStoreLocation ,[String]$certificateStoreName, $pfxPassword)
{
    $pfx = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2    

    $pfx.Import($certPath, $pfxPassword, "Exportable,PersistKeySet")    

    $store = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store($certificateStoreName,$certificateStoreLocation)    
    $store.open("MaxAllowed")    
    $store.add($pfx)    
    $store.close()
    return $pfx
}
```

Answer (score 2):

2008 R2 uses `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`

Via PowerShell you can see the certs available to IIS here:

```
cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

You can cd into that location and look for your cert. Once you find it you can view its private key ID using:

```
$cert = get-item 2779B37AE3625FD8D2F9596E285C7CDC15049D87
$cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
```

This will contain the long hexadecimal filename from the MachineKeys folder.

You can then change the file permissions using the `Set-Acl` cmdlet.

You can also view the permissions via the Certificates MMC `mmc/add snapin/certificates/computer account/local computer` and then `certificates/personal/certificates/[your cert]/all tasks/manage private keys`

Comment: Please see my updated post, and check `Get-LocalMachineCertificate` function

Comment: No I mean post the code installing the key pair from the PFX into the cert store. The private key files are in that folder on my 2008 R2 VM.

Comment: Are you sure its going in the machine store not the user store? `C:\Users\[NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\[SID]`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I found it in roaming folder. But I can see my certificate in local machine's store in my MMC, what is wrong?

Comment: Make sure your script is installing it to `cert:\LocalMachine\My`

Answer (score 0):

If you drag and drop a certificate from User Store\Personal to Computer Store\Personal, the $getCert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName value is wrong. There is no file with that value. Import the certificate again in the right store and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

here is a complete powershell script to give permission to any user on certificate's private key.

[How to Grant permission to user on Certificate private key using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046916/how-to-grant-permission-to-user-on-certificate-private-key-using-powershell/40046917#40046917)

Above link has script and example how to run it on powershell console window.

If you are using ApplicationPoolIdentity then you username will be **'IIS AppPool\AppPoolNameHere'**

**Note**: You will need to use **' '** as there is a space between IIS and AppPool.