# Windows Docker IIS App Pool not able to read certificates from local cert store

Tags: docker, dockerfile, x509certificate, client-certificates, pfx

I've asp.net MVC website hosted within docker container. The site needs to read the certificates stored on cert:\currentuser\my and present it to the Azure AD for app authentication.

I've loaded the pfx certs on to docker as part of image build per below:

```
# Install cert, located at certs folder in the host machine, relative to the path of the Solution Dockerfile
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR C:\certs
COPY ./certs .\

RUN Get-ChildItem -File | Foreach { Import-PfxCertificate -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "xyz1234" -AsPlainText -Force)  -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -FilePath $_.fullname }
```

Then have this simple test aspx to read the cert by thumprint:

```
public X509Certificate2 FindCertificateByThumbprint(string findValue, bool validateCertificate)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                findValue, validateCertificate);
            if (col == null || col.Count == 0)
                return null;
            return col[0];
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Note:**

1. On non docker (local laptop), This works perfectly OK for web.
2. On docker container, console app can find the certificate but not web app.

I tried all these but no luck:

https://newbedev.com/how-to-grant-permission-to-user-on-certificate-private-key-using-powershell

[How to Grant permission to user on Certificate private key using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046916/how-to-grant-permission-to-user-on-certificate-private-key-using-powershell)

https://www.codyhosterman.com/2019/06/assigning-read-access-to-windows-private-key/

Feels like I'm missing a step here but not sure what. Has anyone got